# BeginAuthenticateAsClient doesn't work in new AppDomain

Tags: c#, serialization, appdomain, sslstream, asynccallback

I am trying to create an `SslStream` object in a new `AppDomain`. However, running the `BeginAuthenticateAsClient` method on the stream causes an Exception to be thrown.

```
internal class SslWrapper : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void CreateStream(Stream innerStream)
    {
        var ioStream = new SslStream(innerStream, 
                                     false,
                                     ValidateRemoteCertificate,
                                     SelectLocalCertificate);

        ioStream.BeginAuthenticateAsClient("Target",
                                           GetCertificates(),
                                           SslProtocols.Tls,
                                           false,
                                           new AsyncCallback(CallbackMethod), 
                                           null);
    }

    private void CallbackMethod(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // TODO: handle callback...
    }
}
```

The exception states:

> The type System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest in Assembly System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 is not marked as serializable.

*Edit:* The exception is thrown after calling `BeginAuthenticateAsClient()`. The `SelectLocalCertificate()` callback method is called, but `ValidateRemoteCertificate()` is not.

The new `AppDomain` and `SslWrapper` are created as follows:

```
_appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(name, null, new AppDomainSetup { PrivateBinPath = pathToDll });
_wrapper = (SslWrapper)_appDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(pathToDll, typeof(SslWrapper).FullName);
_wrapper.CreateStream(innerStream);
```

Using the synchronous `AuthenticateAsClient()` instead works successfully, as does running the asynchronous code in the default `AppDomain`.

I assume the exception is related to the AsyncCallback method.
However, this method should not be crossing the AppDomain boundary, so why might I be getting the exception? More importantly, is it possible to avoid it?

I am using .NET 2, WinXP 64bit.

*Edit:* This is also a problem in .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

the problem should be in your **innerStream** object, it has to be serializable or MarshalByRefObject in order to work(i.e. be able to be passed as parameter across AppDomain boundary)

Comment: But it is passed without problem in the _wrapper.CreateStream(innerStream) call. It is only the callback which fails.

Comment: how does it 'fail' exactly? on which line do you get the exception thrown?

Comment: A SerializationException is thrown immediately after calling BeginAuthenticationAsClient()